# NPM instalation local issue

Tags: apt, software-installation, uninstall, nodejs, npm

I've read [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli/tutorial) how to install `npm`.
Tryed:

```
~ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo -E bash -
~ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
~ nodejs -v
>> v0.10.48
~ node -v
>> v7.4.0
~ npm -v
>> bash: / usr / local / bin / npm: No such file or directory
```

try to install `npm` directly:

```
~ sudo apt-get install npm
npm: Depends: nodejs but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (> = 1.0.4) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-ansi but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (> = 0.1.22) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but he will not be installed
       Depends: node-glob (> = 3.1.21) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (> = 2.0.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-ini (> = 1.1.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (> = 2.3.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (> = 0.2.11) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (> = 0.3.3) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-gyp (> = 0.10.9) but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (> = 2.1.1) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-once but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (> = 1.1.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-request (> = 2.25.0) but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (> = 2.2.2) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-semver (> = 2.1.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-sha but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it will not be installed
       Depends: node-tar (> = 0.1.18) but it is not installed
       Depends: node-which but it will not be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have delayed (held) broken packages.
```

Lets see held

```
~ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
>> [no results]
```

Is any ideas to try?

---

**More details after trying to do something:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install / usr / bin / node nodejs / usr / bin / nodejs 100
update-alternatives: error: alternative link / usr / bin / node already controlled node
```

I tried continue with next instruction without solving previous error (i do not know how to solve it).

```
~ sudo curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
/ Usr / local / bin / npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/ Usr / local / lib
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! argv "/ usr / local / bin / node" "/tmp/npm.26355/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm v4.1.1
npm ERR! path ../../../../../tmp/npm.26355/package/man/man1/npm-access.1
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../../../../../tmp/npm.26355/package/man/man1/npm-access.1' -> '/ usr / local / share / man / man1 / npm-access.1 '
npm ERR! {Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../../../../../tmp/npm.26355/package/man/man1/npm-access.1' -> '/ usr / local /share/man/man1/npm-access.1 '
npm ERR! errno: -13,
npm ERR! code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR! path: '../../../../../tmp/npm.26355/package/man/man1/npm-access.1',
npm ERR! dest: '/usr/local/share/man/man1/npm-access.1'}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root / Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /tmp/npm.26355/package/npm-debug.log
It failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, remove npm (you already know how), remove nodejs, do an `apt-get autoremove`. Next:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node nodejs /usr/bin/nodejs 100
sudo curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh
```

That should be it.

Comment: it seems I need something else, see details in general question.

Comment: my bad, try the last command like this: `sudo curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh`

Comment: Let me clarify one thing. Before installing nodejs I should not have any (npm, node or nodejs). I have found my `node` does not removed, may be because of  unempty `node_modules`, do not know. But I hope this info helps you to help me :)

Comment: `node` can be called, but if i try uninstall `sudo apt-get remove --purge node` i get an message `Package 'node' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: ok, start over and remove nodejs `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`, then do `sudo apt-get autoremove` - it will remove unused packages. Then proceed with the installation

Comment: It's a partly remove. I did it, it helps to uninstall nodejs, but node was not uninsatlled. I tried your last recomendation: `sudo curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh` it installed npm for me and node was accessible, but I do not have nodejs now :). I confused with my environment configuration it seems very corrupted. I'll try work with it, but let me know please if you have more ideas.

Comment: install nodejs, you will need it